# Web deployment task failed (vs2013)

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-webapps

I successfully deployed 'my project 22' from visual studios 2013 express to microsoft Azure. 
It was working fine for about 30 mins.... but now it is giving me an error when loading the projects url http://myproject22.azurewebsites.net/ in browser.

Error 403 - This web app is stopped.

The web app you have attempted to reach is currently stopped and does not accept any requests. Please try to reload the page or visit it again soon.

If you are the Administrator of this web app, please visit the Azure Portal to check why the app is stopped.

---

When i try  to publish the solution i get this error

### Web deployment task failed. (Could not connect to the remote computer ("myproject.scm.azurewebsites.net") using the specified process ("Web Management Service") because the server did not respond. Make sure that the process ("Web Management Service") is started on the remote computer.  Learn more at: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=221672#ERROR_COULD_NOT_CONNECT_TO_REMOTESVC.)

I have tried downloading published profile in azure, putting the file in vs folder publish profiles.
And publishing the project again.
I've noticed in the publish web window validate connection yields failed  and once clicked yields the same error

But it has not resolved the issue.

Anyone any ideas what may be causing the error?